# The meaning of "отводная стрельня"

Tags: значения

> Со стороны Верхнего озера главный вход в башню прикрывался **отводной стрельней**.

I have found the definition of стрельня:

> Стрельня - башня в древнерусском крепостном зодчестве.

But what is `отводная стрельня`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possbible to find the word *стрельница* in dictionaries. It must be the same as *стрельня*. Such **ARCHAIC** words may have different variants, because they had been used by people quite before formalised texts and dictionaries were created. *Отводная* is derived from the word *отвод* (or *отводить* - direct or turn smth., change or tap smth.) - my guess is it implies that this fortification was at a slight distance from the main fortress (not part of the main structure, connected with it through a bridge, or wall, kind of a tapped auxiliary tower for protection). At least, most sources (sources on architecture, Russian Kremlin, etc.) imply that it is so. Some sources mention *барбакан* as something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is the same as ["отводная стрельница"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD), which is just a [barbican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbican).